# How to Redirect to a specific Page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

In the Php, I have a `URL` like

- http://domain.com/referralcode

When I clicked the URL I need to Redirect to particular page

- http://domain.com/invite.php.

How can I achive this. Plz help

Comment: Use a function header('Location : http://domain.com/invite.php');
More about this function : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect `/referralcode/` to `/invite.php` you can use the following redirect in `/.htaccess`

```
RedirectMatch ^/referralcode/?$ /invite.php
```

Comment: and how does he manage to maybe `refcodeabc` -> invite.php?1 || `refcodexyz` -> invite.php?123123 ??